# Date retrieval in android

Tags: android, date

In my application i have 3 text view arranged horizontally,1st previmage,2nd date,3rd nextimage.Now,when i click the 1st textview i should should display the previous month,(its printing) when once again i click means it should  go to 2nd previous month of current month and this should go on..But when i click 2nd time it is coming the 1st previous month only its doesn't going backwards..Please help me.Thanks in advance..

This is my code:

```
prvmon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {       
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Inside left");
            TextView date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
            Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(cal.MONTH,-1);
            Date date1=cal.getTime();
            System.out.println("sssssss="+date1);
            cal.setTime(date1);
            SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM yyyy");
            String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());  
            date.setText(month_name);   
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/ go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are initializing your Calender instance everytime. So, its taking the current date/time instance. So, better would be initialize in once and use it again. Declare it globally and initialize it in `onCreate()`.

```
Calendar calendar = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
...
}
```

now, use this calender instance in your `onClick()` event.

Comment: Thanks Lalit Poptani..Fantastic..Its working like a charm...I will accept ur answer.BUt SO didn't allow for particular time to accept

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date1=cal.getTime();
```

you're always setting it to the same time and 'going back exactly one month into the past'. So, define your Date date1=cal.getTime() outside of the onClick OR keep track of how many months you need to substract, by e.g. incrementing some value at the end of the onClick().

EDIT:

ok so let's take a look at your code again

```
final int clicks = 0; //we'll use this to track clicks
prvmon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        int monthsToGo = --clicks;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside left");
        TextView date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
        Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(cal.MONTH, monthsToGo); //now it'll deduce -1 then -2 etc...
        Date date1=cal.getTime();
        System.out.println("sssssss="+date1);
        cal.setTime(date1);
        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM yyyy");
        String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());  
        date.setText(month_name);   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Shark..But how its possible???I tried but nothing happening..Can u elaborate ur idea???

Answer (score 0):

may be a full example will help:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MonthActivity extends Activity {

    private Calendar calendar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        updateTextView(textView);

        Button prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevCmd);
        prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                updateTextView(textView);

            }
        });

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextCmd);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                updateTextView(textView);

            }
        });
    }

    private void updateTextView(TextView textView) {
        textView.setText(""
                + calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT,
                        Locale.getDefault()));

    }
}
```

and the Layout XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout12"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevCmd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text=" &lt; " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextCmd"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/prevCmd"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Jul"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextCmd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text=" > " />

</RelativeLayout>
```